# table-layout fixed with mixed px and %

Tags: html, css, html-table

I recently discovered that a table with `table-layout:fixed` works fine with any units set to its columns. (absolute or relative)

my scss is very simple: i mixed px and %

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid;

  &:nth-child(1) {
    width: 150px;
  }
  &:nth-child(2) {
    width: 150px;
  }
  &:nth-child(3) {
    width: 200%;
  }
  &:nth-child(4) {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

so even if columns widths summary more than width of a table - it works just fine. I tried to search for explanation of this kind of magic in w3c but found only this

> Any remaining columns equally divide the remaining horizontal table
>   space (minus borders or cell spacing).

these words about remaining, but not the overflow in my case. Please help me to find explanation of this behavior in standarts, cause I am going to use this in my project, but i'm not sure that it's not a bug or whatever.

link to fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/chesminsky/ga3ev2ex/

PS: sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remaining space, after the cell with pixels is set, will be divided in 200% for 3:rd column and 100% for the 4:th.

Which means 2/3 and 1/3 of whats left, so if you were to change the 3:rd and 4:th column to 66% and 33%, you will end up with same end result, but if you make those as well pixel width, they either overflow with a horizontal scroll or the stretch compared to the pixel width percentage of total width.

So what happens is, the 2 columns, with their combined width, comes off the containers total width, before it calculate the ones with percent, as pixel width has higher priority being a fixed size unit.

Src: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#width-layout

Comment: yeah, but percents  should be calculated from the width of outer container. but not in this case. that confuses me

Comment: @GrigoriyShishmintsev Yes, but when pixel is set to 2 columns, their total width comes off containers total width before it calculate the ones with percent, as pixel width has higher priority being a fixed width.

Comment: i see. px when overflow can break the table. but % are kinda soft and not gonna break. but where these words in standarts ? :)

Comment: @GrigoriyShishmintsev Exactly where you found them, the quot in your question, _Any remaining columns equally divide the remaining horizontal table space (minus borders or cell spacing)._

Comment: i thought it is said about columns with no specified width. But i specified them in %.

Comment: @GrigoriyShishmintsev That is the only [spec's existing](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#width-layout) (and it is a vague one), still, all browsers behaves the same.

Comment: @GrigoriyShishmintsev Remove all the width's and they divide equal, in your case, 25%, which means they set themselvle to auto (percent), based on the amount of columns, 1/amount

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug. What you are seeing is called wrapping

If you would like to change that you can specify in CSS

`white-space: nowrap;`

I fixed your example, as you can see its all in one line.

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h1jgp254/)

Comment: but borders remains the same. i wonder, why px has more priority than %. why % not being calculated from the width of outer container

Comment: @GrigoriyShishmintsev In this case `white-space` doesn't change the computed width of the cells with percent, it just tells the content of the cells to not break line